# How to access the body of an http request

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making an http request to hit an endpoint using Python's request library as shown below:

```
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:...',data = {...})
```

If i model this request on Postman i get as a result an object like shown below:

```
{"o":1}
```

which is what my endpoint returns.

However if a manually do the request i can't access this object.The request reaches my server just fine like a erquest from postman.

I tried `r.json()` but this prints an int value of `1015` which i don't understand how it is generated.Is it an error code?
I've been stuck in this for a while,any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `r.text`?

Comment: @gribvirus74 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

Comment: It's not a function. Just do: `print(r.text)`

Comment: Besides, when you're issuing `requests.get` you should pass parameters as `params={...}` not `data={...}`. Maybe this is causing your problems.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `r.content` to get the binary data
- Use `r.text` to get the string (using an encoding such as UTF-8)
- Use `r.json` to get the json dictionary

I don't know why you are getting 1015 - this may be specific to your output.